# mysqldump stopping after first table

Tags: mysql

I've an odd behavior with one of my script in charge of dumping databases.

Most of the time, the script is working fine, dumping the databases properly, but regularly between 4am to 6am, the script fails to dump all the databases's structures and data : it stops at the first table dumped.

To be very clear, it doesn't depend on the database targeted by the script, but really depends on the time, cause most of the time, all databases targeted by the dump are OK, and another day, few databases targeted by the dump will be not-completely dumped.

According these 'time clues', I think the host where is running my script is subject to night reboot, but I don't understand why the dump stops always exactly at the same table such as follow:

```
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.1.63, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: inpg
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version       5.1.63-0+squeeze1-log

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

--
-- Table structure for table `accounts`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `accounts`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `accounts` (
  `id` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_entered` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified_user_id` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_by` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` text,
  `deleted` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `assigned_user_id` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `account_type` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `industry` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `annual_revenue` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone_fax` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `billing_address_street` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `billing_address_city` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `billing_address_state` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `billing_address_postalcode` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `billing_address_country` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rating` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone_office` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone_alternate` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `website` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ownership` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `employees` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ticker_symbol` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `shipping_address_street` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `shipping_address_city` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `shipping_address_state` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `shipping_address_postalcode` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `shipping_address_country` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `parent_id` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sic_code` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `campaign_id` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lead_source` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `zone_geographique` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `taille_structure` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `siret` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cle` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `team_create_id` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx_accnt_id_del` (`id`,`deleted`),
  KEY `idx_accnt_name_del` (`name`,`deleted`),
  KEY `idx_accnt_assigned_del` (`deleted`,`assigned_user_id`),
  KEY `idx_accnt_parent_id` (`parent_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

Does anyone have encountered such behavior with mysqldump ?

Thanks for your help

Cheers

Comment: What happens if you dump this table only from the command line (`mysqldump your_database your_table > /dev/null`)? Any error message?

Comment: depending on your configuration, @RandomSeed's method may try to output errors to the target file, in his case `/dev/null`.  When I have had issues with mysqldump in the past the errors in the target file indicated views referencing missing tables.

Comment: `mysqldump` sends such errors to `stderr`, so `mysqldump >/dev/null` should show errors on the console.

Comment: thanks for your help, but the command given by RandomSeed did not show any errors

Comment: I investigated a bit more my problem, and I found out something about the parameter `wait_timeout`. I did get all of the explanationd, in my case do I use a noninteractive connection ? Cheers